# Неправильно подключается статический CSS файл к Flask

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, flask

У меня возникла странная ситуация. Я создал простое приложение на Flask и решил попробовать подключить к нему CSS файл. Создал папку static добавил туда css файл. Вот содержимое файла:

```
body{
    color: red;
}
```

Все работало, весь текст приобрел красный цвет.
Затем я изменил содержимое этого файла

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Я сохранил файл, перезапустил сервер, обновил сайт, но он остался таким каким был. После этого я вообще удалил все из CSS файла, сохранил его, перезапустил сервер, обновил сайт, но там все так-же был красный цвет! Кто знает почему при изменении CSS файла он как-будто не меняется?

Comment: А если Ctrl+F5?

Comment: Чистить кэш пробовал? Так же попробуй добавить новое имя при подключении css файла.

Было: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
Стало: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?=1">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того что файлы стилей кэшируются у тебя в браузере.

Отчистить кэш можно с помощью `CTRL+F5`.

Но пользователи твоего приложения не будут сбрасывать кэш каждый раз, когда заходят на твой сайт.

Можно отключить кэширование совсем

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

Но более правильным подходом является указывать версию у твоих стилей, каждый раз когда ты их изменяешь. Так браузер сам обновит кэш, когда увидит, что у пользователя старая версия. `v=1`, `v=2` и так далее.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for( 'static', filename='style.css', v=1)}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в самом приложении `Flask`, сделать такую настройку

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Подключить статику в темплейте таким образом

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for( 'static', filename='index.css')}}">
```

Либо попробуйте CTRL+SHIFT+R в браузере (если у вас хром), сделать жесткую перезагрузку страницы.